# Why canvas fill() does not paint the shape with the color specified in fillStyle?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fill

Why doesn't `c.fillStyle` color the triangle?

```
var c= document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

//c.fillRect(20,10,250,175);//

c.moveTo(225,75);
c.lineTo(112.5,225);

c.moveTo(112.5,225);
c.lineTo(337.5,225);

c.moveTo(337.5,225);
c.lineTo(225,75);

c.strokeStyle= '#9e9e9e';
c.stroke();

c.fillStyle= '#ffc061';
c.fill();
```

Comment: Improved grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because calling the `moveTo` method after `lineTo` breaks the filled area by jumping to a new current position. You can solve this problem by removing `moveTo` methods, like this:

```
c.moveTo(225,75);
c.lineTo(112.5,225);
c.lineTo(337.5,225);
c.closePath();

c.strokeStyle = '#9e9e9e';
c.stroke();

c.fillStyle = '#ffc061';
c.fill();
```